# Laravel Excel Storing Under a directory inside Disks

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Laravel Excel to Create Excels Files, I have multiple Excels for one Projects to be download say 10 Excel Sheets which runs on Queue which I have to zip it after storing all the files.

I have a disk configures in `filesystems.php` like so

```php
'exports' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => storage_path('app/public/poc'),
]
```

Now when I store the Excels I create a folder under the disk like `organizationsName` and then I want to store inside that folder inside to the disk directly.

Currently my code is like so

```php
$organization = $project->first()->load('organization')->organization->name;
Storage::disk('exports')->makeDirectory($organization);
foreach ($project as $p)
{
   Excel::store(new DownloadProjects($project, $p->id), $poc->title.' Project Data.xlsx', 'exports');
}
```

How can I store the Files inside the Disk's Directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($project as $p)
{
    Excel::store(new DownloadProjects($project, $p->id), /<path to folder from export disk>/$poc->title.' Project Data.xlsx', 'exports');
}
```

Change your excel store second parameter as the above one. Just mention the path to the required space from the mentioned disk.